# Not able to send transaction due to contract runner

Tags: ethers.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

import { contractABI, contractAddress } from '../utils/constants';

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext<any>({});

const { ethereum } = window as any;

const getEthereumContract = (): ethers.Contract => {
    console.log(contractAddress)
    console.log(contractABI)

    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();

    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
    console.log(provider, signer, contract)

    return contract;
}

export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }: any) => {

    const [currentAccount, setcurrentAccount] = useState(null);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState<any>({ addressTo: '', amount: '', keyword: '', message: '' });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] =
        useState<number>(
            parseInt(
                localStorage.getItem('transactionCount') ? localStorage.getItem('transactionCount') as string : '0'
            )
        );

    const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
        if (!ethereum) {
            return alert('Make sure you have metamask installed!');
        }
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });

        if (accounts.length) {
            setcurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
        }

    }

    const handleChange = (e: any, name: string) => {
        setFormData((prev: any) => ({ ...prev, [name]: e.target.value }))
        console.log(formData)
    }


    const connectWallet = async () => {
        try {
            if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")
            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            await setcurrentAccount(accounts)
            console.log(currentAccount)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            throw new Error("No account found")
        }
    }

    const sendTransaction = async (): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")
            const {
                addressTo,
                amount,
                keyword,
                message
            } = formData;
            const transactionContract = getEthereumContract()
            const parsedAmount: bigint = ethers.parseEther(amount)
            console.log(currentAccount)
            console.log("--------------")
            console.log(addressTo)

            await ethereum.request({
                method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                params: [{
                    from: currentAccount,
                    to: addressTo,
                    value: parsedAmount.toString(16),
                    gas: (21000).toString(16),
                }]
            });

            const transactionHash: any = await transactionContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

            setIsLoading(true);
            console.log(`Loading ${transactionHash.hash}`)
            await transactionHash.wait()
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.log(`Done ${transactionHash.hash}`)

            const transactionCount = await transactionContract.getTransactionCount();
            setTransactionCount(transactionCount.toNumber());
            console.log(transactionCount.toNumber())

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfWalletIsConnected();
    })

    return (
        <TransactionContext.Provider value={{
            connectWallet: connectWallet,
            currentAccount: currentAccount,
            formData: formData,
            setFormData: setFormData,
            handleChange: handleChange,
            sendTransaction: sendTransaction,
            isLoading: isLoading,
        }}>
            {children}
        </TransactionContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Here I am getting console error, I have double-checked my contract abi's and contract address they are right, but still I am not able to interact with the contract.

Here is the error:

```
TransactionContext.tsx:103 Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.2)
    at makeError (errors.ts:677:21)
    at assert (errors.ts:694:25)
    at send (contract.ts:288:9)
    at Proxy.addToBlockchain (contract.ts:330:22)
    at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.tsx:90:68)
sendTransaction @ TransactionContext.tsx:103
await in sendTransaction (async)
handleSubmit @ Welcome.tsx:53
onClick @ Welcome.tsx:156
callCallback2 @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Show 15 more frames
```

Comment: Did "const signer = await provider.getSigner();" solve your problem? I am getting the same error and not sure where the root cause coming from.

Comment: I think there are some changes in ethers version 6 method, because when I was passing signer to the contract it was forbidding to take the object, I searched about the method but I was not able to found the answer, then after a lot of searching I deleted ethers version 6 and used old method of ethers version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Put an await in your signer.

```
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
```